# Accessing local eval inside function scope

Tags: javascript

Please consider the two following snippets of code:

```
(function f() { 
    var x;
    try {
        eval("x");
        console.log('No error!');
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log('Error!');
    }
}(eval))
```

and

```
(function f(eval) { 
    var x;
    try {
        eval("x");
        console.log('No error!');
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log('Error!');
    }
}(eval))
```

The first prints `No error!`, the second prints `Error!`. Is there a way to access "local `eval`" inside a function scope for which `eval` is one of the arguments?

Comment: You shouldn't use `eval` as a parameter name. It's confusing and bad practice.

Comment: Okay then! I answered! Don't make a habit of it though :)

Comment: Your parens `}())` for an anonymous function call, are kind of messed up.  Should be `})()`

Comment: @vol7ron: Either one will work.

Comment: Could you review your question? I think right now there is no point in this question.

Comment: @Randomblue: Chrome doesn't give me an error. Are you in "strict mode"?

Comment: @Randomblue: I have Chrome 17 beta on Mac, and no error for me... unless I use strict

Comment: I run them in V8 engine. They show `No Error!`

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me - , but there was no value passed in the original question, too.  I still haven't seen ol' Doug ever post that, but it makes sense, since parenthesis are magically optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global functions are part of the `window` object. Call `window.eval()` instead.

Comment: Works for me! http://jsfiddle.net/bT9SA/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to use

```
window.eval()
```

in this case