# Distinguishing local eval from global eval

Tags: javascript

Please consider the two snippets of code (the first prints "Local eval", the second prints "Global eval"):

```
(function f() { 
    var x;
    try {
        eval("x");
        console.log('Local eval');
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log('Global eval');
    }
}())
```

and

```
var globalEval = eval;
(function f() { 
    var x;
    try {
        globalEval("x");
        console.log('Local eval');
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log('Global eval');
    }
}())
```

It turns out that even though `globalEval === eval` evaluates to `true`, `globalEval` and `eval` *behave differently* because they have different names. (An eval can only be local if it is precisely written `eval`.)

How can I distinguish to two evals? Is there are a way to extract variable labels to infer behaviour?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: I'm trying to build an example of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223517/pure-function-given-strictly-equal-arguments-yielding-non-strictly-equal-results). I'm close, but not quite there yet.

Comment: Why didn't you just stick with [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145385/accessing-local-eval-inside-function-scope)?

Comment: @amnotiam: It's kind of different, and I got confused. I wish I could delete it.

Comment: This article explains it all: http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting.  But since you're in control of where/when your reference to `eval` is defined, you get to say how to distinguish them.  For example have an object that has the "function pointer" AND something to indicate the scope - if you define it, you know where you stand.

I.e. `myEvaluator.scope` would tell you info about where the eval scope was captuerd, and `myEvaluator.eval` could be used to evaluate.